# DialogFragment is attached incorrectly after orientation change

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I have the following structure in my Android application:

[Main FragmentActivity] -> [DialogFragment #1] -> [DialogFragment #2] -> [DialogFragment #3 (Calendar / Datepicker)]

Now, when I am in the **DialogFragment #3** selecting a date, and I rotate the device and the previous state is restored, the **DialogFragment #3** isn't any longer attached to **DialogFragment #2** but instead it's attached to the **main activity** (Main FragmentActivity).

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this behavior?

**EDIT 1**:

I am using the support library.

Per request here is the code used to show the fragments.

To show **DialogFragment #1**

```
String tag = classDialog_1.class.getCanonicalName();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if(prev != null)
    fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
classDialog_1 instanceClassDialog_1 = classDialog_1.newInstance();
instanceClassDialog_1.show(fragmentTransaction, tag);
```

To show **DialogFragment #2**

```
String tag = classDialog_2.class.getCanonicalName();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if(prev != null)
    fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

classDialog_1 instanceClassDialog_2 = classDialog_2.newInstance(paramA, paramB);
instanceClassDialog_2.show(fragmentTransaction, tag);
```

To show **DialogFragment #3**

```
String tag = this.getClass().getName() + classDialog_3.class.getCanonicalName();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
if (prev != null)
    fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

classDialog_3 instanceClassDialog_3 = classDialog_3.newInstance(paramC, paramD, paramE);
instanceClassDialog_3.show(fragmentTransaction, tag);
```

**EDIT 2**:

As suggested in the answer below the code was modified as follows but didn't work (example with **DialogFragment #3**):

```
String tag = this.getClass().getName() + classDialog_3.class.getCanonicalName();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
/* This section wasn't removed since without it the dialog ( instanceClassDialog_3 ) wasn't showing up. */
if (prev != null)
    fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

classDialog_3 instanceClassDialog_3 = classDialog_3.newInstance(paramC, paramD, paramE);
instanceClassDialog_3.show(fragmentTransaction, tag);
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the support library? Can you show the code you're using to show the fragments?

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your code, your `DialogFragment`s will only ever be attached to the `Activity`. They will never be attached as child `Fragment`s.

First, you really shouldn't need to remove the previous instance of the DialogFragment before showing it again -- Android handles keeping it across configuration changes, so you can just check:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) != null) {
    // Show your DialogFragment
    ClassDialog1 dialog = ClassDialog1.newInstance();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), tag);
} else {
    // DialogFragment is already showing
}
```

Now, your issue as I understand it is that your want your other `DialogFragment`s to be child `Fragment`s of `ClassDialog1`? If so, you need to use the `Fragment`'s `FragmentManager` -- not the `Activity`'s.

If you're in an `Activity` class:

```
// This is the Activity's FragmentManager
getSupportFragmentManager();
```

If you're in a `Fragment` class:

```
// This is the Activity's FragmentManager
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

// This is the Fragment's FragmentManager
getFragmentManager();
```

If you want the `Fragment` attached to another `Fragment`, you need to use the hosting `Fragment`'s `FragmentManager` instead of the `Activity`'s.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but unfortunately, at least how I did it, didn't work. On each fragement that spawned another fragment I used getFragmentManager like this: FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  Fragment frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

Comment: In else statement you stated that dialog is already showing, how i can get that "already displayed dialog" there so that i can dismiss it?